# How I can use a web application as interface to my application which build in C++?

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio-2012

first  : I build a web application by visual studio .

second : I build another application using visual studio by (C++) .

third  : the user must write the input to my application (which I build it in C++,visual studio) on the web application (which I build it in C#,visual studio).

My question is : 
How I can to take the input (which the user inserted on a web application and put it (Export it ) to a text file )from the web application .

NOTE : I need the input to use it in my application which I build it in C++.

Comment: What have you tried? This seems to be a "please do my homework for me" question

Comment: no , I only want to make a web application as interface to another application build by (C++) , this is my problem I work on a big project not homework

Comment: @sam Well, the easiest way might be to provide your application with a CGI interface.

Comment: ok , I will try the CGI interface ... thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

A text file to save the data from the web app is like using a bicycle wheels as landing gear for a plane. What you can do is write the web inputs to an SQl database or MS Access then while still using C# (no need to use C++) you can read the data and write it to a txt file. C++ on web is hectic very few people have done it. Also you can use JSON.

Comment: I need to use flex and bison (I can't use c# with flex and bison) ... I want to check from an expretion (enter on web) and then I want to build an application in c++ (because I must to use flex and bison ) @j0nimost